# How I can open a connection to a SQL Server by using T-SQL script and execute a ETL task?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

When I tried this script, I got an error indicating that the login had failed. However, I am able to initiate a connection with the server normally from the SSMS environment

```
USE MyDB;
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE MyDB.dbo.MyTable

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'MySer', N'SQL Server';
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'MySer', 'false', 'Uname', 'pw';

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name, NameEn, Acronym)
    SELECT 
        r.R_Id, 
        r.R_Desc, 
        r.R_Desc_E, 
        ''
    FROM 
        MySer.RemoteDB.dbo.RemoteTable r;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your linked server add datasource and catalog.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
      @server = N'MySer', 
      @srvproduct=N'', 
      @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', 
      @datasrc=N'YourRegistratedServerName', 
      @catalog=N'RemoteDB';
    go
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
      @rmtsrvname=N'MySer',
      @useself=N'False',
      @locallogin=NULL,
      @rmtuser=N'Uname',
      @rmtpassword = N'pw' ;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**